# SSRF - Internal network surfing

Tags: iis, ssrf

If an IIS web server exposes a site in INTERNET, is it possible for an attacker to access internal sites by simply modifying the host header of initial request to internet site and refer another host name of internal site ?

```
GET http://site1.com/ HTTP 1.1
Host: site2.intranet
```

Through the above request, is it possible for an attacker to get content from the intranet site ?

Comment: This is not a valid HTTP request. Apart from that, it depends on the specific server configuration.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Thanks for the remark. Also, why this would not be a valid http request ?

Comment: *"why this would not be a valid http request"* - because at least the protocol version is specified wrong, it should be `HTTP/1.1` not `HTTP 1.1`. Also, the full URL should only be given in a proxy request not in a normal request - there should only the path `/` be given. In theory the full URL could be given with HTTP/1.1 (but not  HTTP/1.0) but many servers don't support this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Indeed, I wrote it manually. However, if this is properly formatted, can such thing occur ? I mean, can you actually access an internal application if you change the host header or the forward host headers ?It bothers me that this basic request manipulation can do such thing to access other sites.

Comment: Again, it depends ... - if it is the same server and the same IP address as the external site then there isn't actually a difference.